# How to store Complex datatypes in Android Room database that includes List<*>

Tags: android, database, android-room, typeconverter

I have 2 tables in one database both are completely separate (no relation between them), I want to store data in room database which has List and this List has other data fields which also includes List<sub_data>. Here is my all data classes.

ChapterSlok class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "slok")
data class ChapterSlok(
    @PrimaryKey
    val chapter_id: Int,
    val slokList: List<ChapterSlokItem>
)
```

ChapterSlokItem Class:

```
data class ChapterSlokItem(
    val chapter_number: Int,
    val commentaries: List<Commentary>,
    val id: Int,
    val slug: String,
    val text: String,
    val translations: List<Translation>,
    val transliteration: String,
    val verse_number: Int,
    val word_meanings: String
)
```

Commentary class:

```
data class Commentary(
    val author_name: String,
    val description: String,
    val id: Int,
    val language: String
)
```

Translation class:

```
data class Translation(
    val author_name: String,
    val description: String,
    val id: Int,
    val language: String
)
```

Here is my DAO interface:

```
@Dao
interface ChapterSummaryDAO {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addChapterSummary(chapters: List<ChapterSummaryItem>)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM chapter")
    suspend fun getChapterSummary(): List<ChapterSummaryItem>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun addChapterSlok(slok: ChapterSlok)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM slok")
    suspend fun getChapterSlok(): List<ChapterSlok>
}
```

And here is my Database:

```
@Database(entities = [ChapterSummaryItem::class, ChapterSlok::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class ChapterSummaryDataBase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract val chapterSummaryDAO: ChapterSummaryDAO

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: ChapterSummaryDataBase? = null

        fun getDataBase(context: Context): ChapterSummaryDataBase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                synchronized(this) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context,
                        ChapterSummaryDataBase::class.java,
                        "chapterDB"
                    ).build()
                }
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Typeconverter Class:

```
@ProvidedTypeConverter
class Converters {
    val gson = Gson()

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromCommentariesList(commentaries: List<Commentary>): String {
        return gson.toJson(commentaries)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toCommentariesList(commentariesString: String): List<Commentary> {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<Commentary>>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(commentariesString, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTranslationsList(translations: List<Translation>): String {
        return gson.toJson(translations)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toTranslationsList(translationsString: String): List<Translation> {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<Translation>>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(translationsString, type)
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromChapterSlokItemList(slokList: List<ChapterSlokItem>): String {
        return gson.toJson(slokList)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toChapterSlokItemList(chapterSlokString: String): List<ChapterSlokItem> {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<ChapterSlokItem>>() {}.type
        return gson.fromJson(chapterSlokString, type)    }

}
```

The error is

```
Unable to create application com.practice.gita.GitaApplication: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A required type converter (class com.practice.gita.Converters.Converters) for com.practice.gita.db.ChapterSummaryDAO is missing in the database configuration.
```

How i can convert this datatypes so it can be stored in Room. Can anyone please help me to modify type converters. As I don't need Commentary or Translation without it's whole ChapterSlok, I tried to @Serializable and encoded to string and decoded to class too. but still getting same error.

Comment: From what I know @ProvidedTypeConverter annotation is used when setting converters in runtime (using `Room.databaseBuilder.addTypeConverter`) Either remove this annotation, or use `addTypeConverter` when creating your DB

Comment: I got the solution, I have to define separate class for storing list, Room does not support storing lists.

Solution :
1. defined data class which includes List<Commentary>
2. Annotated this field with `@Embeded`
3. Removed `@ProvidedTypeConverter` from Converter class.

And voila, It's done!